# Install FPDF on Laravel 4

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, fpdf

I didn't manage to install FPDF on laravel 4.
Can you help me?
Can you explain how to do it step by step?

I add on `composer.json`

```
"require": {
         "illuminate/support": "4.0.x"
    },
"require-dev": {
        "anouar/fpdf": "dev-master"
    },
```

after this, on shell, I use composer update. And now?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To your composer.json file, add:

```
"require-dev": {
    "anouar/fpdf": "dev-master"
}
```

Then update your Laravel project,

```
composer update
```

If not already installed laravel framework use,

```
composer install
```

Then go to app/config/app.php and to the providers array add,

```
'Anouar\Fpdf\FpdfServiceProvider',
```

Now it's look like,

```
'providers' => array(
    // ...

    'Anouar\Fpdf\FpdfServiceProvider',
)
```

Finally, add the alias to app/config/app.php, within the aliases array.

```
'aliases' => array(
    // ...

    'Fpdf'    => 'Anouar\Fpdf\Facades\Fpdf',
)
```

Now you can use `Fpdf` anywhere like,

In app/routes.php

```
Route::get('pdf', function(){

        Fpdf::AddPage();
        Fpdf::SetFont('Arial','B',16);
        Fpdf::Cell(40,10,'Hello World!');
        Fpdf::Output();
        exit;

});
```

Then test it with your url like,

```
http://localhost/laravel/pdf
```

You can see the Packagist https://packagist.org/packages/anouar/fpdf

And the GitHub Repo here https://github.com/xroot/laravel-fpdf

Answer (score 0):

the fpdf is external component and you must create a workbench to integrating this to laravel.
this is smiliar [tutorial]http://jasonlewis.me/article/laravel-4-develop-packages-using-the-workbench

or you can use other component. [dompdf]http://packalyst.com/packages/package/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf